# Is it possible to scroll recycle view line by line?

Tags: java, android, user-interface, scroll

I'd like to add a custom time picker to my application.

There is recycle view with fixed size that allowed only three items (lines) at time. When I scroll it - it scrolls smoothly thus I fix position of element by this code:

```
    @Override
        public void onScrollStateChanged(@NonNull RecyclerView recyclerView, int newState) {

            int f = layout.findFirstVisibleItemPosition();

            layout.scrollToPosition(f);

            adapter.setCurrentPosition(f + 1);
}
```

It say to the LinearLayout find the first visible element and scroll to it. Thus I have it as first line, then selected time value as second line. The third line we can see because of the height of the RecycleView same item height * 3.

I think it too complex. Is there some Layout parameter or some  other Layout that can provide scroll line by line?

[The video sample](http://youtu.be/ocxripGOF40)